# Searching text files for string patterns that are each defined in their own classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strings, .net

I'm trying to implement interfaces in my design but not sure if this is correct or if there is a better way to do it.

What I need to do is

1. open a text file
2. keep searching blocks of text until I find a string that matches against one of the classes that defines that string pattern
3. process the string I found
4. continue processing file where I left off

This is the code I'm using so far, but not sure if the design is correct.
Maybe something about creating a new instance of each stringType class just to check if the string matches with the one defined in the class seems wrong to me. I don't need to create the instance of the object until I actually need to do work on it.

**EDIT - Forgot to add the process function, not sure if that changes anything**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //get types that implement IStringType interface
    List<IStringType> types = TypeFactory.GetTypeList();

    //scan text file and check against the types, store any matches found
    var stringMatches =  from t in types
                        where Regex.IsMatch(sourceString, t.stringPattern)
                        select t.getNewInstance(Regex.Match(sourceString,t.stringPattern).Value);

    if (stringMatches.Any())
    {
        //process string matches
    }
}
public class stringType1 : IStringType
{
    public string stringPattern { get { return @"(?m)^TEST1.+[\r\n]"; } set { this.stringPattern = value; } }
    private string _Message { get; set; }

    public stringType1() { }
    public stringType1(string str)
    {
        _Message = str;
    }

    public string ProcessString(string match)
    {
       //specific code to processes stringType1

    }
    public IStringType getNewInstance(string msg)
    {
        return (IStringType)(new stringType1(msg));
    }
}

public class stringType2 : IStringType
{
    public string stringPattern { get { return @"(?m)^BLAH2.+[\r\n]"; } set { this.stringPattern = value; } }
    private string _Message { get; set; }

    public stringType2() { }
    public stringType2(string str)
    {
        _Message = str;
    }
    public string ProcessString(string match)
    {
       //specific code to processes stringType2

    }
    public IStringType getNewInstance(string msg)
    {
        return (IStringType)(new stringType2(msg));
    }
}       

public interface IStringType
{
    string stringPattern { get; set; }
    string ProcessString(string str);
    IStringType getNewInstance(string str);
}


public static class TypeFactory
{
    public static List<IStringType> GetTypeList()
    {
        List<IStringType> types = new List<IStringType>();
        types.AddRange(from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                       where t.IsClass && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IStringType))
                       select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IStringType);
        return types;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's very easy: you shouldn't. An interface is used to indicate that a subset of classes present common behaviour or should be considered similar in some way.

In your situation there simply is no reason to make this change because all you do is change a text value in a property, which could just as easily be done by taking an argument in your constructor and keeping a `private` backing fields which should then be used to populate the property's regex.

This will result in several code optimizations:

- No heavy duplication of code in `StringType1` and `StringType2` (this should have been a red flag)
- No reflection necessary to get the different types. Just keep a collection of the different regexes and return a collection of `StringType` objects, constructed with your regexes.

Additionally, this code will also be obsolete:

```
public IStringType getNewInstance(string msg)
{
    return (IStringType)(new stringType2(msg));
}
```

since you should just overwrite that variable with `new Stringtype(thisVariable.StringPattern, message)`.

Ultimately, your code would look something like this:

```
public class StringType
{
    private IPatternProcessor _processor;
    private string _pattern;
    private string _message { get; set; }

    public StringType(string str, IPatternProcessor processor)
    {
        _message = str;
        _processor = processor;
    }

    public string StringPattern { 
        get { return pattern; } 
        set { pattern = value; } 
    }

    public void Process() {
        _processor.Process(_message);
    }
}    

public static class PatternFactory
{
    private static List<String> _patterns = new List<String>();

    static PatternFactory() {
         _patterns.Add("(?m)^TEST1.+[\r\n]";);
         _patterns.Add("(?m)^BLAH2.+[\r\n]";);
    }    

    public static List<StringType> GetTypeList()
    {
        return _patterns.Select(x => new StringType(x));
    }
}

public interface IPatternProcessor { 
    void Process(string input);
}

public class ProcessMethod1 : IPatternProcessor { }
public class ProcessMethod2 : IPatternProcessor { }
```

If you want to make it easy for your user, you can hardcode these different methods into properties:

```
public class PatternProcessor {
    public IPatternProcessor ProcessMethod1 { get { return new ProcessMethod1(); } private set; };
    public IPatternProcessor ProcessMethod2 { get { return new ProcessMethod2(); } private set; };
}
```

Now you can simply call this with

```
new StringType(input, PatternProcessor.ProcessMethod1).Process();
```

If you were really into it, you could just cache the `IProcessMethod` objects in a collection in your `PatternProcessor` class (provided each method is stateless), but that might be going a little too far out of the scope of this review.

## Style notes

- Classes are UpperCamelCase (`StringType`)
- Private fields are less standardized but they are often written as `_field`
- Methods and constructors are always capitalized (`StringPattern`, `StringType`), just like the class

## Conclusion

This code does not benefit from interfaces at all and as such it is impossible to review it since interfaces are the main problem with the code.

## Post-edit

So, with the additional requirement of pattern-specific behaviour the introduction of interfaces and separate types now makes a lot more sense. I see two architecture options off the bat:

- Separate `StringType` classes for each situation (if you name them `StringType1`, `StringType2` etc, I'll chase you with a bat)
- Separate strategies (strategy pattern) for each type of processing with a sauce of factory pattern

I will go with the second option because it would require less rewriting. Someone else can write the less complex first option but the second option is more flexible in terms of allowing two different patterns to use the same processing option.

I will change the earlier block of code with some additions to keep everything in one place.

Comment: `static { _patterns.Add("(?m)^TEST1.+[\r\n]";); [...]` won't compile, it's not Java ;) it should be `static PatternFactory` instead. The answer is on the nose anyway

Comment: but I need to process each string different, each stringType class for example has a process() function that processes the string specifically for each type

Comment: @Morawski: cheers, feel free to edit yourself though! I always switch it up between C# and Java ;)

Comment: @erotavlas: why would you leave out the entire reason why someone would use an interface.. If anything had to be in there, it was that `process()` method.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel I know I'm so sorry :/

Comment: We can still salvage this, don't worry. Give me a few moments to introduce you to the strategy pattern.

Comment: @erotavlas: I have expanded upon my answer

Comment: +1 for *if you name them StringType1, StringType2 etc, I'll chase you with a bat* ;)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel it seems like a a pretty good approach, but I'm wondering now how I can associate which PatternProcessor to pass, each processor belongs only to one pattern, is that just something I have to take care of before I pass the parameters into the StringType constructor? (i.e. I have to external to this find a way to link the string with the correct processor before passing them in)

Comment: If you want to explicitly combine them then you can incorporate something you did earlier: different classes that hold a pattern and a processor and then you can simply instantiate the class that you want and you'll get the pattern and the processor combined. In the end this will look quite a bit like your original solution, but there is an extra layer which allows you to reuse the same processor and the interface usage feels more clean.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't see how the PatternFactory is used in the code sample.  How would it be used to invoke the correct PatternProcessor based on the input string?